# If $A$ and $B$ are compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, is then $ A × B $ compact?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, compactness

If $A$ and $B$ are compact subsets of $\mathbb{R ^ n}$, is then $ A × B $ compact?
I think it is because it's then closed and bounded because A and B are closed and bounded?

Comment: That is indeed a way to prove that in this context. More generally it can also be proved that $A\times B$ is compact if $A$ is a compact subset of topological space $X$ and $B$ is a compact subset of topological space $Y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument is correct.

More generally, of $X$ and $Y$ are any compact topological spaces, $X\times Y$ is compact too, by [Tychonoff's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff%27s_theorem).

Comment: The last argument assumes the OP already knows that $\mathbb{R}^2$ also has the product topology wrt its factors.